# Why it closed the connection directly when time out rather than call the closeHandler method?

Tags: go, websocket

Why it closed the connection directly when time out rather than call the closeHandler method?

```
ws.SetCloseHandler(func(code int, text string) error {
    fmt.Println("socket close")
}
// can not get "socket close"
stdout: "websocket: close 1006 (abnormal closure): unexpected EOF"
```

package: "github.com/gorilla/websocket"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [websocket RFC](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6455) says this about status 1006:

> 1006 is a reserved value and MUST NOT be set as a status code in a
> Close control frame by an endpoint.  It is designated for use in
> applications expecting a status code to indicate that the
> connection was closed abnormally, e.g., without sending or
> receiving a Close control frame.

The [websocket package documention](https://godoc.org/github.com/gorilla/websocket#Conn.SetCloseHandler) says:

> SetCloseHandler sets the handler for close messages received from the peer

The close handler was not called because a close message was not received. The peer closed the connection without sending a close message.

The package documentation also says:

> The connection read methods return a CloseError when a close message is received. Most applications should handle close messages as part of their normal error handling. Applications should only set a close handler when the application must perform some action before sending a close message back to the peer.

Because the handler in the question does not send a close message or take any other action, the close handler in the question is not needed.  The handler is harmful because it does not echo the close message.

Delete the close handler and handle close messages as part of the application's normal error handling.

Comment: so, I shuold use error(err := ws.ReadJSON(&msg)) to handle abnormal closing？

Comment: Given the code that you posted, your application should use the error returned from the read methods to handle **all** errors.  Delete the close handler.